# AOSP : debug EthernetManager SystemServices

Tags: android, service, static, ip, android-source

I currently trying to set static IP for eth0 in boot phase on Android device.

I try to do that using java service and no script or something else to not bypass java android service.

I see that there is a hack in Android by using EthernetServiceImpl with the setConfiguration method.

My code is pretty simple. I get ETHERNET_SERVICE (EthernetManager) with :

```
EthernetManager ethernetManager = (EthernetManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ETHERNET_SERVICE);
ethernetManager.setConfiguration(config);
```

That doesn't work. It should create "ipconfig.txt" in "/data/misc/ethernet".

When I debug my service (I don't register it as System service, it a simple service), I see that in ethernet managed, the value service is null. But this should be set in the constructor.

EthernetManager.java :

```
/**
 * Set Ethernet configuration.
 */
public void setConfiguration(IpConfiguration config) {
    if (mService == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mService.setConfiguration(config);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
```

Does anyone have success using this service? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution and what IDE you are using to debug it